# Why use ImmutableList over ReadOnlyCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, immutable-collections

.NET 4.5 has a new namespace [System.Collections.Immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable(v=vs.111).aspx)

> This package provides collections that are thread safe and guaranteed to never change their contents, also known as immutable collections.

I'm confused. Isn't the thread safety problem already solved by the [ReadOnlyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class? Why use [ImmutableList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) instead?

---

I know there's also an [IReadOnlyList *interface*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That doesn't solve the thread safety problem implicitly, because other threads may edit the object by another interface.

Comment: This post seems to explain it fairly well " http://blog.slaks.net/2013-06-11/readonly-vs-immutable/ "

Comment: Just for infomration `System.Collections.Immutable` has to be installed through nuget package manager. I had to do so in a project targeting .Net framework 4.6.2.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

With a [`ReadOnlyCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132476(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper
>   that prevents modifying the collection; therefore, if changes are made
>   to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those
>   changes.

This can't happen with an `ImmutableList`.

Comment: I would suggest the most important feature of immutable collections is how they are manipulated by creating new immutable collections and the underlying efficient "copy-on-write" mechanisms. Therefore the other two answers seem to be more relevant to me.

Comment: Immutability is a big lie at least in C# .Net. I'm not sure about other programming languages. In C# even with `ImmutableList` anyone can go via unmanaged route and change the contents of that memory location without CLR's knowledge. But yes as long as all the parties abide by the legalities offered by .Net platform we can safely assume `ImmutableList` is immutable indeed.

Comment: @RBT it's the same for any program really - if you've got code running inside the same process, the OS won't stop you changing anything

Comment: Even Immutable collection can be modified by modifying underlying collection.
I am unable to understand why we say it can't be done?

Comment: @AshwiniMohan If you use the proper public API of `ImmutableList`, there is no underlying collection to modify - when you call `Add` etc, it returns a new copy of the collection with the additions - the original is left untouched.  With `ReadOnlyCollection`, while you can't modify it through that class itself, you can still modify the underlying collection that `ReadOnlyCollection` was initialised with.  If you start using reflection or other methods of modifying data, then yes - anything goes, as per my previous comment.

Comment: Right, that's what my understanding is. Definitely thread safety is an advantage with immutable list but at last, everything is modifiable.
In ReadOnly list, it just takes only single foreach loop, and for immutable list, it takes another nested foreach to modify. Maybe I was over expecting. 
But thanks @JamesThorpe for the explanation. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 40):

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` doesn't solve any of the thread safety problems. It is merely a wrapper around `Ilist<T>`. It doesn't exposes members to modify the collection, but you can always modify it with the underlying collection reference.

If the underlying collection is modified, it isn't safe to enumerate the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. If you do, you'll get the same `InvalidOperationException` with message "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute...".

From [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A ReadOnlyCollection can support multiple readers concurrently, as
>   long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a
>   collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. To guarantee
>   thread safety during enumeration, you can lock the collection during
>   the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by
>   multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

`ImmutableList` on the other hand is immutable and thus inherently thread safe.

Answer (score 36):

`ReadOnlyCollection`, as the name suggests, can only be read.

On the other hand, you can append/remove items to/from an `ImmutableList` by calling its `Add`/`Remove`/`Clear` methods, for example, which return a new immutable list.

Comment: I'll add that this makes the `ImmutableList<>` very similar to a `string`.

Comment: @xanatos indeed, or to any (properly implemented) value type.

Comment: With ImmutableList, isn't the important distinction, just like string, that you're not modifying the original. You're creating a new object with the change (say with Remove) but the original version remains unchanged?

Answer (score 10):

In multi-threaded scenarios, be advised that read-only collections are still not thread-safe.

From the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` documentation:

> ... if changes are made to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those changes

Since collections, like `List<T>` and others, are not thread safe, so is not the read-only collection.

**Important**: There are some corner cases which you won't find explicitly explained in MSDN. Some of the operations that seemingly only read content of a collection, are in fact modifying the internal structures of the collection. Why is this not specified? - One obvious reason is because that is an implementation detail which doesn't reflect on the API. The result is that even if you don't modify the `List<T>` wrapped into an `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, and only use getters, the crash could still happen in multi-threaded environment!

Bottom line is that common collections, even when wrapped into a `ReadOnlyCollection` cannot be used in multi-threaded environment out of the box.

As opposed to `ReadOnlyCollection`, immutable collections do guarantee that none of the internal structures will ever change after a reference to a collection has been obtained. Note that these structures are still not truly immutable. They are, instead, *freezable*. That means that the structure will internally change for a while until it is *frozen* and returned to the caller. Beyond that point, all other calls on the immutable collection will only make modifications outside the structures accessible through the original reference.

Conclusion: Read-only collections are *not* thread-safe; immutable collections are thread-safe.

Answer (score 4):

So far all technical aspects was told but no code.
I created a small example shows main difference.

Consider both readonly collection and immutable list pointing **same object** in this case ***"strings list".***

If we add a new item to ***"strings list"*** after readonly collection creation , we can see that readonly collection is modified.(So we managed to find a way to mutate readonly collection)

However,when we take same steps on immutable lists,immutable list stays intact

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>()
{
    "Visual Studio 2017","Visual Studio 2019"
};
ReadOnlyCollection<string> readOnlyStrings = strings.AsReadOnly();
var immutableList = strings.ToImmutableList();
strings.Add("Visual Studio 2022");
Console.WriteLine("Readonly List");

foreach (string item in readOnlyStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.WriteLine("Immutable List");

foreach (string item in immutableList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The main benefit is memory efficiency, not thread-safety.

The immutable collections in [System.Collections.Immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-6.0) are designed in a way that allows modified versions of the collection to share data structures with un-modified copies of the same collection. The differences are encoded in clever ways that don't require duplication of the whole data structure. There is nice explanation of this at [Immutable Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/net-framework-immutable-collections).

[ReadOnlyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) requires a completely seperate copy of the collection to be created whenever a modification is made. This uses more memory and puts a higher load on the garbage collector.

As you've observed, both classes seek to guarantee that the collection can't have observable modifications. And both classes achieve that to some extent, assuming they aren't misused.

Comment: *"`ReadOnlyCollection` requires a completely separate copy of the collection to be created whenever a modification is made."* -- Why? Why create a copy, and not just modify the collection? The owner of the collection can always modify it. It's only the users of the read-only facade that can't mutate the collection.

Comment: Having a single owner who is able to mutate the collection and multiple read-only users who never create modified versions is certainly a common situation. However, in some other situations the read-only users will want to take the old collection and create a new collection that adds, removes or modifies an element. This second use case is the one where immutable collections may be more efficient.