# What is the difference between returning an Array and an IList<>? (RE: Eric Lippert's harmful arrays)

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, return-type, mutability

I just read [Eric Lippert's "*Arrays considered somewhat harmful*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful) article.  He tells his readers that they "probably should not return an array as the value of a public method or property," with the following reasoning (slightly paraphrased):

> Now the caller can take that array and replace the contents of it with whatever they please. The sensible thing to return is `IList<>`. You can build yourself a nice read-only collection object once, and then just pass out references to it as much as you want.

In essence,

> An array is a collection of variables. The caller doesn’t want variables, but it’ll take them if that’s the only way to get the values. But neither the callee nor the caller wants those variables to ever vary.

In an attempt to understand what he meant by variables vs. values, I built demo class that has `Array` and `IList<>` fields, and methods that return references to both.  [Here it is on C# Pad.](http://csharppad.com/gist/cae586b881f74894e049)

```
class A {
    
    private readonly int[] arr = new []
    {
        10, 20, 30, 40, 50    
    };
    
    private readonly List<int> list = new List<int>(new []
    {
        10, 20, 30, 40, 50
    });
    
    public int[] GetArr()
    {
        return arr;
    }
    
    public IList<int> GetList()
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, the `GetArr()` method is Lippert's bad practice, and `GetList()` is his sensible practice.  Here is a demo of the bad caller mutability behavior of `GetArr()`:

```
var a = new A();
var arr1 = a.GetArr();
var arr2 = a.GetArr();

Console.WriteLine("arr1[2]: " + arr1[2].ToString());  // > arr1[2]: 30
Console.WriteLine("arr2[2]: " + arr2[2].ToString());  // > arr2[2]: 30

// ONE CALLER MUTATES
arr1[2] = 99;

// BOTH CALLERS AFFECTED
Console.WriteLine("arr1[2]: " + arr1[2].ToString());  // > arr1[2]: 99
Console.WriteLine("arr2[2]: " + arr2[2].ToString());  // > arr2[2]: 99
```

But I don't understand his distinction - **the `IList<>` reference has the same caller mutation problem:**

```
var a = new A();
var list1 = a.GetList();
var list2 = a.GetList();

Console.WriteLine("list1[2]: " + list1[2].ToString());  // > list1[2]: 30
Console.WriteLine("list2[2]: " + list2[2].ToString());  // > list2[2]: 30

// ONE CALLER MUTATES
list1[2] = 99;

// BOTH CALLERS AFFECTED
Console.WriteLine("list1[2]: " + list1[2].ToString());  // > list1[2]: 99
Console.WriteLine("list2[2]: " + list2[2].ToString());  // > list2[2]: 99
```

Obviously, ***I trust that Eric Lippert knows what he's talking about*, so where have I misinterpreted him?  In what way is a returned `IList<>` reference safer than an `Array` reference?**

Comment: I think what's missing here is following this advice: "You can build yourself a nice read-only collection object once, and then just pass out references to it as much as you want."  Though, to be fair, it's reasonable nowadays to return an array, but type the return value as an `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Comment: The most common reason to prefer an interface (`iList` in this case) is its adaptability (i.e., you can fullfil the given requirements in many different ways unlike with `string[]` for example, which only accepts a very specific format); and this is the point being made here. Nothing to do with arrays as such (but with its not so adaptable essence). IMHO (and by having very clear that Eric Lippert certainly knows much more about .NET languages than I do), this kind of generic statements are rarely good. Arrays are the ideal approach in certain situations and iLists (or even Lists) in others.

Comment: Your example seems to say that you have to return a `List<T>` for an `IList<T>`, but you can return the array as well, as arrays implement `IList<T>`; however, be careful, you cannot use the `Add()` method in this case.

Comment: @DanBryant, thanks for the response!  Though I have a couple issues.  1) I thought I *did* "*build a nice read-only collection*"?  You're right - that must be where my confusion is.  2) Regarding returning the array as a safer type, "*do not simply cast the array and think you’re done.  The caller can simply cast back to array.*"

Comment: @varocarbas No, it really is to do with arrays themselves. There is no possibility of making an array read-only. So if you return an array, you cannot prevent the caller from modifying that array. So if you return a list-like structure, and return it as an array, you cannot safely cache the array between for subsequent calls. That's the whole point of the blog post. Therefore, if caching the list is desirable or there is any real chance of it becoming so in the future, don't return arrays. I'm not denying there are exceptions, but if you have to ask if your case is one, it probably isn't.

Comment: One minor tidbit, if you intend to pass back a read-only collection typed as an `IList<T>`, while _technically_ this is correct (as we have the [`IList<T>.IsReadOnly` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), I think it's better to type it as a `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead (assuming you're using .NET 4.5 or higher). Reason being that `IList<T>` is generally consumed as a mutable collection and has a mutable API. A lot of times, people assume that if they have an `IList<T>` or `List<T>` they can change it.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Also, for convenience, you can use helper utility methods like [`Array.AsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53kysx7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`List<T>.AsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which create read-only wrappers around the underlying collection. (Mind you, modifications to the underlying collection still reflect in the "read only" wrappers. But if you are sure you won't be modifying the underlying collection, then these are nice light wrappers you can use to avoid making copies of the collection.)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, after reading the other answers and comments for context, your response is among the most clarifying.  [This C# pad](http://csharppad.com/gist/317fb99452b1231f6080) demonstrates it.  Returning `IList<>` instead of `IReadOnlyList<>` violates the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Had that article been written today it would have almost certainly suggested using `IReadOnlyList<T>`, but that type didn't exist in 2008 when that article was written.  The only supported means of having a read-only indexable list interface was to use an `IList<T>` and simply not implement the mutation operations.  This *does* let you return an object that the caller can't mutate, although it's not necessarily clear (particularly from the API) that the object is in fact immutable.  That drawback in .NET has been remedied since then.

Comment: There's a ton of good info in this thread, but this bit of history really clears it up.

Comment: Had this answer been written today (2022), it might suggested using [`ImmutableArray<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1) or [`IImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutablelist-1). :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Meh, that's a discussion related to changing the implementation details.  The publicly exposed API probably wouldn't want to be either of those things (and would make sense staying as an `IReadOnlyList<T>`, even if there was a compelling reason to change the actual underlying implementation from a mutable list/array/etc. to an immutable data structure.

Comment: Servy the `IImmutableList<T>` is an interface that communicates immutability. The `IReadOnlyList<T>` is not. See [Why use ImmutableList over ReadOnlyCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165810/why-use-immutablelist-over-readonlycollection).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The whole point of the question though is asking about providing a read only interface to a mutable object.  The way it had been done in the past was to copy the data to an array (or other data structure) and return it, now the framework mutable data structures all implement immutable interfaces.  Yes, you can possibly avoid the problem entirely by not using mutable data structures, that's true.  I'm not even sure it'd be appropriate in the few specific examples used here, but certainly in general they *sometimes* could be.

Comment: I read the question more carefully (I hadn't done so when I posted my comment), and I think that the main point of the question is to get into Eric Lippert's mind when he wrote his 2008 article. If he had written the article today, would he had switched from the `IList<T>` to a `IReadOnlyList<T>` or an `IImmutableList<T>`? I am not sure. He might had suggested both, explaining the differences between the two.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah, that's fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

Returning a `List<T>` object as an `IList<T>` is not what he is recommending. Instead, you should create a read-only object that implements `IList<T>` and return that. For example, you could use a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` object.

Comment: "*Returning a List<T> object as an IList<T> is not what he is recommending.*"  I think you're right.  I guess I was just thrown off because the `IList<>` interface expresses mutability.  Everything would've been much clearer if he suggested returning an `IReadOnlyList<>` directly.

Comment: @kdbanman `IReadOnlyList<>` didn't exist yet at the time of the blog post. If he had written it today, I'm convinced `IReadOnlyList<>` would be used. :)

Answer (score 2):

He is referring to the ability to implement `IList<T>` with a read-only concrete type:

> If you are writing such an API, wrap the array in a ReadOnlyCollection and return an IEnumerable or an IList or something, but not an array.  (And of course, do not simply cast the array to IEnumerable and think you’re done!  That is still passing out variables; the caller can simply cast back to array!  Only pass out an array if it is wrapped up by a read-only object.)